# Formatting Phone Numbers with country code in PHP

Tags: php, phone-number

I am working on website that the customer submit his phone number and need to be able to convert the customer's phone number from `0553322111` to `966553322111` so I can use it to compare with the records in a MySQL database.

How would I go about this with PHP?

---

When the user submit his phone number in the HTML Page

He will submitted as `0553322111`.

**PHP**

```
<?php
// store the submitted num.
$temp = $_POST['number']; >> 0553322111.
?>
```

I want to use $temp value that stores the number and modify it to `966553322111` so I can query the records with the new value.

Comment: So if you have country code and the phone number what's the issue then? Just small changes

Comment: Could you post some code that shows what you already have tried or where you get stuck?

Comment: What if they enter an international number?

Comment: I edited it, check the example above. THANKS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use preg_replace:

```
$phone_number = preg_replace('/^0/','966',$phone_number);
```

/^0/ = 0 at the start of the string

So it basically says, replace 0 at the start of the string with 966

let me know if this works.